# 3D Arrays in Android saved before app is closed

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an android app that relies on multiple 3-d arrays to run (both string arrays and int arrays). The app works fine, except when the app is restarted (force-quit, crash, or stopped), the arrays are reset to their original value. I need the changes made to the arrays to be saved and reloaded when the app is closed and re-opened. I have 3 activities that all need information from these arrays. I know that shared preferences can only hold strings, not arrays. I'm am having trouble finding an example of how these changes can be saved and re-opened on ANY activity.

```
String coursePath [][] = {{"CSIT 101","NURS 201", "NURS 301", "NURS 014","NURS 501","NURS 601","NURS 017","NURS 186", "NURS 187","NURS 188","NURS 189","NURS 190"},{"ENGR 101","ENGR 201", "ENGR 210", "ENGR 211","ENGR 254","ENGR 256","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289","ENGR 289"}
int courseStatus [][] ={
        {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};
int courseUpdate [][][] ={
        {{4,5,6},{4,5,6},{4,5,6},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}},
        {{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
};
int courseRequired [][][] ={
        {{0,1,2},{0,1,2},{0,1,2},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}},
        {{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
};
```

Comment: give try with `realm`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SQLite` or any other database and make such database structure.

Then using `onPause()` or `onStop()` or `onBackPressed()` you can save those values to database.